# Including grid system to include table - Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, random

I'm trying to position the ***EN | FR*** elements in my footer. I would like to center these elements like the other elements of my footer (Contact Us and Connect). Would anyone have tips for me? This is my code.

```
   <footer class="container-fluid text-center">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3>Contact Us</h3>
      <br>
      <h4>Our adress and contact info here</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3>Connect</h3>
      <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
      <a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
      <a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
      <a href="#" class="fa fa-google"></a>
      <a href="#" class="fa fa-youtube"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" id="lang-sel">
      <table>
        <thead>
        <tr id="langues">
          <th>FR</th>
          <th>|</th>
          <th>EN</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

[How it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85AAI.png)

Comment: <h3>FR  |  EN</h3>

Answer (score 0):

Take the EN/FR out of the table and just use a div to wrap them. Then you could use CSS to center them:

```
#lang-sel {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the only thing is that I need them to be links and to be inline so I don't think I can take them out of the table... Tried span as well but couldn't add the desired margin and padding.

Answer (score 0):

there 
if you use bootstrap 4, then just put some css to `.row` class.
http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/73120/

Comment: Thank you!! Was using bootstrap 3.3.7 but I will now migrate to Bootstrap 4. Very useful answer, cheers.